# How to create the new target in Xcode for app extension using CMake?

Tags: ios, xcode, cmake, ios-extensions

I want to use Notification Content Extension in my `Xcode` project.
I use CMake to generate my project. 
Now the project has only one target.

I can add the extension as new target manually in `Xcode` using menu File - New - Target - `Notification` Content Extension.

Could you provide an example how to create new `Xcode` project with additional target for app extension by using CMake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since CMake 3.8, you could use `XCODE_PRODUCT_TYPE` target property to let CMake generate specific type of application.

Minimal example that should troubleshoot you:

```
# add app bundle
add_executable(MyApp MACOSX_BUNDLE ${APP_SOURCE_FILES})

# add app extension bundle
add_library(MyAppExtension MODULE ${APPEX_SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(MyAppExtension PROPERTIES
    BUNDLE YES
    XCODE_PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.app-extension)

# link extension bundle with UserNotifications frameworks
find_library(UN_LIB UserNotifications)
find_library(UNUI_LIB UserNotificationsUI)
target_link_libraries(MyAppExtension PRIVATE ${UN_LIB} ${UNUI_LIB})
```

Answer (score 1):

I tested on cmake3.23 on mac, app extension is a executable not library. It should be like this:

```
add_executable(MyAppExtension MACOSX_BUNDLE ${APPEX_SOURCE_FILES})
set_target_properties(MyAppExtension PROPERTIES
    XCODE_PRODUCT_TYPE com.apple.product-type.app-extension)
```

Then you can embed app extension to app :

```
set_target_properties(MyApp PROPERTIES
        XCODE_EMBED_APP_EXTENSIONS MyAppExtension)
```